# How to Include other CMake projects in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, cmake, native-code

Recently, I'v been developing a native c++ project with Android studio, which needs some other external open source libraries. I want to involve these libraries (for example, hello library)inside the Android Studio project by using CMake's add_subdirectory command to ease my code management. I refer the online guide doc from https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake, but not completely. Concretly, I add the following items to my top level CMakeList.txt:

```
set( lib_src_DIR /Users/dependencies/hello-1.1.1 )
set( lib_build_DIR /Users/dependencies/hello )
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${lib_build_DIR})
add_subdirectory( ${lib_src_DIR} ${lib_build_DIR} )
```

the whole top level CMakeLists.txt post as the following picture:
[image: top level CMakeLists.txt]

Everything's done, I build this project, what I expect to see is libhello.a in the /Users/dependencies/hello directory, but there's only some Cmake related files, like following:
[image]

Thers's no libhello.a found in the hello directory and its subdirectories, it seems like my hello library is not compiled at all. The following picture is my hello project's CMakeList.txt:
[image]
I'm sure this hello project can compile because I tried use cmake command to compile it directly, it's ok.

So, why add_subdirectory in the top level CMakeLists.txt don't work? Was I missing some other settings ? By the way, this top level CMakeLists.txt was genereated by the Android Studio automatically when I create the native C++ project, I just add something in it.

Comment: do these external dependency libraries have to be compiled individually ?

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using images with the text (code, error message, etc.). Please, replace images of code with the itself. See also [ask].

Comment: Where do actually use (link against) the `hello` static library?

Comment: well, it's not the key point. hello is just for my test, I didn't link against it yet. But even this , it still suppose to be generated. But with STATIC, it's not compiled. While using SHARED, it's can generate libhello.so . There's a post discussing about this problem long ago, I found it on the website and convice myself it's the Android Studio's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that's the Android Studio's bug, it only can generate synamic libraries(.so), if you specify the library as static, it won't compile.